# What is the significance of these scores?

Tags: probability

My brain doesn't work right anymore.  I have a traumatic brain injury and one of the many areas I have trouble with is math - an area that was once naturally easy and intuitive for me.  I remember standard deviations, generally, and have read up on what they indicate broadly and how they are reached.  When I was tested for my brain injury, there were some tests in which my abilities were worse than 3 SDs below the mean! [I am a professional with a master's degree, and was one of those students who aced everything with ease.  This information on my current condition, however, matches pretty well, I think, my current state, post injury.  I struggle greatly with many varied kinds of things.]

So far as I can recall, 1 SD is a significant enough deviation that I don't recall anyone ever talking about anything greater than 2 SDs above or below the mean.  So my question is how "bad," may I ask, are scores such as: 0.7 SD below the mean, 1.7 SD below the mean, and  a score of 3.2 SDs below the mean.  I am asking for general but concrete advice on how to interpret these numbers generally, of course, and hold no one there responsible.  I just want to better understand the significance of my scores, mathematically. The brain injury staff mince and avoid answering my questions about this, so maybe someone here will help me understand this information.

Thank you kindly for your assistance.

Comment: Compare this to other more everyday scenarios.  In America (and most of the rest of the world) the average height of an adult human male is relatively well modeled by a normal distribution with the average height being 5'9" with a standard deviation of 3".  3.2 standard deviations below the mean is like being an adult male at 4'11".  (notation being 4 feet and 11 inches for those unfamiliar)

Comment: Thank you, as well, for giving such a concrete example.  I wish I had come here a year ago when the testing was done and I was trying to grasp the significance of my scores.

Comment: Medical advice from professional neurologists/neuro-surgeons is more valuable in the restoration process than those here.  Lots of rest, exercise and relaxed reading or tasks that you always enjoyed, taking in proper energy foods ( I heard  about folic acid, amino-acids, vitamins in   5-hour Energy drink, plain Gatorade like fluids, but doctors' recommendation is best. )

Comment: Note that you can only receive the answer from those who administer/calibrate the test. Normal approximation in the tails in NOT applicable in general. The test could be calibrated to a normal only upto 2 STD, hence severely underestimating tails.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty low.  With a normal distribution, 99.7 percent of the population lies within 3 standard deviations from the norm (between -3 and +3), that means the remaining .3 percent is split between the top and bottom. 95 percent is with 2 standard deviations and 68 percent is within one standard deviation.

So:

- -1 SD would have 16 percent of the population below it.
- -2 SD would have  2.5 percent of the population below it.
- -3 SD would have only .15 percent of the population below.

Standard deviations are a way to represent what is called a *normal distribution*, so basically you have an average and the population is distributed on both sides.  There is not really a good way to compute it by hand, but it is typically looked up in a table or done using a calculator function.  It is essentially a bell curve, and the percentages correspond to the area under certain parts of the curve.

- $-0.3$ would have about 38% below
- $-0.7$ would have about 24% below
- $-1.7$ would have about 14% below
- $-3.2$ would has less than 1% below

Comment: THANK YOU!  This is exactly the information I have been seeking!  How lovely of you to clarify these numbers.  I knew the scores were horrible but had no concrete memory of just how bad.

Comment: Not to belabor this to death, but I still can't figure out how to translate numbers such as - 0.3 SD, -0.7 SD, -1.7 SD, and -3.2 SDs into real numbers.  I am guessing that - 0.3 SD = lower than 47.6% of the population.  Is that correct?  And even if it is, I can't figure out the others.  Would you be able to do the math, and perhaps show me how you did it?

Comment: Note: this is a 20 y/o TBI which I realized WAS a TBI 1 year ago.  In a professional TBI journal, I read there are about 20 MILLION people with undiagnosed TBIs!  I was 1 of them.  Doctors missed it entirely as I never lost consciousness when a car slammed into me as he blew a red light. A whiplash is all it takes. Skull moves faster than brain, which floats in viscous fluid.  Skull gets to the end of one 'snap' and returns but brain hasn't got to the end yet, meaning it slams into skull as skull returns. Brain can drag on rough lower surface of skull, too. Back and forth, over and over. Ugly.

Answer (score 0):

*Theoretically* it means about a 1 in 700 level of low performance.

Practically there is some variability in the measurement.  Maybe it could have been 2.5 or 3.4 standard deviations if measured at a different time, location, amount of sleep beforehand, or any number of other factors.  This leads to variability in the "1 in 700".   Think of it as a fuzzier "one in hundreds" level of low performance, where if large numbers of (perfectly randomly selected) people take the same diagnostic tests, between 99 and 99.9 percent will obtain a better result than that.

There is also a limit to the accuracy of the normal distribution ("bell curve") assumptions on scores.  For mental tests, extremely high or low outcomes are much more common than predicted by the bell curve that is used to convert the 3 standard deviations into a percentile or probability or "1 in 700" type of summary.  Doctors could avoid this by reporting results as a percentile, based on actual populations of patients or test-takers, and not theoretical normal distributions.  An approximation to that is to ask the doctors to quantify, within their experience of patients, what percentage are better or worse than this outcome.  They may be reluctant to give precise answers so as not to discourage patients, and rightly so. Placebo effects and unjustified confidence can help patients recover.

Finally, mental diagnostic tests, especially the ones used for people with brain injuries, tend to report multiple numbers from subtests related to memory, vision, language, etc, and not a single IQ-like score for overall performance.  Part of the point of this is to help identify which brain regions are more injured than others.

Having trouble with math may be an easier thing to overcome than other deficits, since calculators and computers might be able to fill in some steps.

Comment: Yes, I do understand how many things can affect scores.  However, the fact is, I have many struggles I never had before, and it is frankly a relief to know and to be able to explain to others that I'm not being stupid or thoughtless or careless when I am late, plan something badly, or forget key aspects to something, but rather that my brain is injured.  For 19 years I called myself a "stupid idiot" when I'd find I'd done something badly. The testing, plus your help with the meaning of my scores is actually a huge boost to my self-esteem!  Think of it as wonderful horrible news.

Comment: I ran out of characters so am back to tell you THANK YOU from the bottom of my very thankful heart.  Your willingness to stick with  me here until I got full understanding is very, very much appreciated.  Take care of your own precious brain, my friend, and best to you in this and every coming year of your life.  Most Sincerely, Beverley Davis

Comment: You are more than welcome.  For the "wonderful bad news" side of things, it is possible that the 3 standard deviations and "one in 700" are a slightly inaccurate measurement of something worse, like 3.2 standard deviations and "one in 1000".  Whatever the true number, clearly some aspects of the scores are far enough toward the low end of the scale to make a definite difference in life.  But it can be hard to find something more informative than "one in hundreds to one in a thousand" as a summary metaphor for that.

Comment: p.s. the Internet search engines catch these things, so if you prefer to be anonymous your last comment can be deleted by moving the mouse over the comment and clicking on the circled X. All the best and good luck dealing with the TBI.  I've hit my own head enough times to worry about it occasionally.